# It is possible to disable required='required' validation in html'?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created on text

```
<input  type="text" required="required" />
```

Is it possible in browser that we can disable this validation.
For example- we can disable javascript in browsers.

Comment: If you don't want the field to be validated don't put the required attribute in there.

Comment: Check out the browser support of this attribute: http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `novalidate` attribute on your form, i.e `<form novalidate..>` to disable browser validation for this particular form

Answer (score 1):

If the browser doesn't support the attribute, it will be ignored, so it won't work. It might already be enough to set an older rendering engine in IE, although I'm not 100% sure. So in the end, yes, you can't be sure the attribute is indeed interpreted and followed. You should still verify the user inputs server side once the form has been sent - or in script in case the form is handled on the client side.